# Why does my output go to cout rather than to file? 

Tags: c++, c, file-io, string-formatting

I am doing some scientific work on a system with a queue. The cout gets output to a log file with name specified with command line options when submitting to the queue. However, I also want a separate output to a file, which I implement like this:

```
ofstream vout("potential.txt"); ...
vout<<printf("%.3f %.5f\n",Rf*BohrToA,eval(0)*hatocm);
```

However it gets mixed in with the output going to cout and I only get some cryptic repeating numbers in my potential.txt. Is this a buffer problem? Other instances of outputting to other files work... maybe I should move this one away from an area that is cout heavy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting your C and C++ mixed together.

`printf` is a function from the c library which prints a formatted string to standard output. `ofstream` and its `<<` operator are how you print to a file in C++ style.

You have two options here, you can either print it out the C way or the C++ way.

C style:

```
FILE* vout = fopen("potential.txt", "w");
fprintf(vout, "%.3f %.5f\n",Rf*BohrToA,eval(0)*hatocm);
```

C++ style:

```
#include <iomanip>
//...
ofstream vout("potential.txt");
vout << fixed << setprecision(3) << (Rf*BohrToA) << " ";
vout << setprecision(5) << (eval(0)*hatocm) << endl;
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually I have no formal training with either C/C++, but the group I'm doing an RA with uses them. So have been hacking together code from their previous work and using cplusplus.com tutorials as a reference.

Answer (score 6):

You are sending the value returned by [printf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) in vout, not the string.

You should simply do:

```
vout << Rf*BohrToA << " " << eval(0)*hatocm << "\n";
```

Comment: OK thanks, but what about formatting the output? Use sprintf to format to a string and output that?

Comment: @ntype You're using C++, so you can use manipulators to help you format your string: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/iomanip.html

Comment: @ntype - for full printf style formatting see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/format/ for simple precision(), width() etc you can use the functions in ostream

Answer (score 0):

If this is on a *nix system, you can simply write your program to send its output to stdout and then use a pipe and the tee command to direct the output to one or more files as well. e.g.

```
$ command parameters | tee outfile
```

will cause the output of command to be written to outfile as well as the console.

You can also do this on Windows if you have the appropriate tools installed (such as GnuWin32).